# Setting vars in ansible and using them as arguments

Tags: yaml, ansible

I want to set variables and use them as parameters later on. This is the code I have

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
      vcenter_hostname: hellothere.hey.com

      user: root

      pass: ohheytherehowareyou


  vars_prompt:

    - name: 'vm_task_action'
      prompt: 'Enter vm action to execute (none, delete)'
      default: 'none'
      private: no


    - name: 'guest_vm'
      prompt: "Enter the guest vm you want to delete"
      default: 'none'
      private: no
      when: vm_task_action == "delete"

  tasks:
    - name: deleting VMs
      vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: vcenter_hostname
        username: user
        password: pass 
        guest: "{{ guest_vm }}"
        state: absent
        force: yes
        when: vm_task_action == 'delete'
```

What is wrong with this code and how do I fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error says for itself:

> 'pass' is not a valid variable name

`pass` is a special keyword, so it can't be used as variable.
Use `mypass: ohheytherehowareyou`, for example.

P.S. also note that `when:` can't be used in `vars_prompt` section.

Comment: Hi. Thanks! I changed it and it fixed it somewhat. That fixed it. I however got a new error when I tried to run it.  I updated the question.

Comment: You shouldn't change topics to the whole different meaning. And a friendly advice: read error messages.